# Bootstrap v3 DateTimePicker not showing value in edit view

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, datepicker

I currently have the Bootstrap DateTimepicker installed and running. It works fine when I used it to enter dates on creation view. However when I use the function on the edit view, the field appears as blank even though there is a value in the model. If you need to edit the date as well, it works fine, click and selecting a date enters correctly and I am able to save the information to the database. However if an edit was NOT made to the field, it will prompt the user for one and then enter the current date. For the purposes of the edit mode, the date field will not always be modified, so I need to preserve the original value if it is not being modified. Below is the generic entry form that was auto generated when I created the view (as an edit)

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.expireat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.expireat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.expireat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the js code I used to access the timepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#expireat').datetimepicker({
            format: "MM/DD/YYYY"            
        })
    });

</script>
```

This is how it looks now. 
[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFRK0.png)

And this is how I want it to look.
[How it is suppose to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkm2d.png)

Is there a setting I can use to achieve this?